# During the command "RAILS_ENV=production script/rails server" I'm getting the following error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 4 column 3 (Psych::SyntaxError)

from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mongoid-2.4.5/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:83:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /opt/graylog2-web-interface/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /opt/graylog2-web-interface/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /opt/graylog2-web-interface/config.ru:in `new'
from /opt/graylog2-web-interface/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Looks like you have an error in one of your YAML config files, possibly the database configuration. Check them for syntax, you are missing a `:` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys I got the solution.
The problem is with **config/mongoid.yml** file where I kept parameter like below

production:

host: localhost

port: 27017

**username:user**  #There should be a space between **:** and **user**.

password: pwd

database: prod

**Correct Way of configuration**

production:

host: localhost

port: 27017

username: user

password: pwd

database: prod

Answer (score 0):

Did you want start rails server in production environment? Could following work:

```
rails s --environment PRODUCTION
```